# SQL Loader error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-loader

I get the below log message from sql loader. Is this message "Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed." a really error? 
At the end i have a log message saying total records read as 74256.  In the ctl control file i see the 38-39 character for record type in each line
and based on it i will insert into different tables.

```
Table TEST1_AA:

  42233 Rows successfully loaded.

  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.

  32023 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.

  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.



Table IIR_TEST2_BB:

  0 Rows successfully loaded.

  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.

  74256 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.

  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.



Table IIR_TEST3_CC:

  31 Rows successfully loaded.

  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.

  74225 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.

  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.



Total logical records skipped:          0

Total logical records read:         74256

Total logical records rejected:         0

Total logical records discarded:        1
```

Sample CTL  File

OPTIONS (ERRORS=9999999999, SILENT=(FEEDBACK), ROWS=1000)

load data

---

into table test_HD

---

append

when (038:039) = 'HD'

(

record_sequence_no             POSITION(029:037) DECIMAL EXTERNAL

,line_type                      POSITION(040:040) CHAR

,header_record_type             POSITION(041:041) CHAR

,enquiry_telephone_number       POSITION(042:052) CHAR

,total_amt_last_bill            POSITION(053:066) DECIMAL EXTERNAL

,total_payment_received         POSITION(067:080) DECIMAL EXTERNAL

)

into table test_AS

---

append

when (038:039) = 'AS'

(

record_sequence_no             POSITION(029:037) DECIMAL EXTERNAL

,line_type                      POSITION(040:040) CHAR

,girn                           POSITION(041:047) CHAR

,charge_desc                    POSITION(048:077) CHAR

}

Comment: Maybe if you posted a sample of the records that were not loaded, what you think should happen to them and the relevant parts of your control file, you might get a useful response. As far as I can see you had a source file of 74256 records some of which were loaded into one table and some of which were loaded into another table. I don't actually see any problem.

Comment: Apparently you have a WHEN clause in your control file, so you should post that control file and some of the rows that were skipped (as Gary has already mentioned)

Comment: More of a guess....but update your when statements to include an 'else' clause so the script knows what to do in the case that none of the conditions in the when statement were met.

Comment: apologies for delayed response. Pasted a sample ctl File.   Not sure "Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed" is a error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error. The log is telling you that 72K records were not loaded anywhere because they did not satisfy any of your WHEN clauses.

In other words, out of 74256 records, 31 had 'HD' or 'AS' in positions 38 and 39, and the rest did not. You also had it skip one line (perhaps the first line is a header row).

That's a successful result if you were trying to load just the 'HD' and 'AS' records.